# Fetch html content from url with redirect

Tags: parsing, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I am porting an application to Windows Phone.

The app is parsing an html page and picking out information from it. 
However, when trying to parse the content I noticed that what I thought was the actual page is just a small page that redirects to the actual content page. 
The URL of the actual page that I want to fetch the data from is actually dynamic.

In my original application I user MaximumAutomaticRedirections like this.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_BaseUrl + "/watch/" + VideoId.ToString());

        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
        request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;

        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Now, MaximumAutomaticRedirections handles the redirects in the windows app, but on the phone sdk, there is no such property.

Do you have any tips on how to get around this?

Best regards, 
Peter Larsson!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone you still have [`HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.95%29) property (which defaults to `true`) but it [seems to does not work as supposed](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/101733/604007.aspx).

Try:

`WebClient` which is wrapper around `HttpWebRequest` but it doesn't hurt to try.

or

Read `Location` header from [`HttpWebResponse.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers).